# Story with opening line about finding God behind the moon

Tags: identification-request

There's a sci-fi story with a cracking opening line.  It goes something like

> It happened around the time they found god, behind the moon, and they sent a fleet of spaceships to tow Her out

I maybe read the story about 20 years ago and I believe it's a fairly well known title.

Comment: "Men are from Mars, Women are from Venus" begins in a similar way (will find the exact quote later tonight). It's not sci-fi though.

Comment: "As he quickly shared his telescope, the sight of these beautiful beings inspired the Martians, and their depression miraculously lifted. Suddenly they felt needed. They came out of their caves and began building a fleet of spaceships to fly to Venus."

Comment: You could try asking over at [the SciFi and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com). Might get more eyes on the question over there.